# how to create nested object from an array with same key (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

`arr = ["sadik", "arif", "rahman"]`

I want to create a nested object with the same key but different value like:

```
{ 
  subcategory: {
    name: sadik
    subcategory: {
      name: arif
      subcategory: {
        name: rahman
      }
    }
  }
}
```

my code:

```
let arr = ['sadik', 'arif', 'babor']
let obj = {}
arr.forEach((elem) => {
  let a = {}
  a["subcategory"] = {name:elem}
  Object.assign(obj, a)
})
```

i get only last value:

```
{
subcategory: {
   name:"babor"
  }
}
```

Comment: We are not a coding service, we can help you with your code but we are not intended to solve your stuff, could you add some code that you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

Your code did not work because you were replacing your "subcategory" key value in each iteration. You have change the reference object to the next nested level each time to get the expected output, see the working snippet below:

```js
const arr = ['level-1', 'level-2', 'level-3']
const obj = {}


let refObj = obj;
arr.forEach( ele => {
  refObj = refObj['subcategory'] || refObj;
  refObj['subcategory'] = { 'name': ele};
})

console.log('output', obj);
```